# Undefined value in ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write simple function in javascript

```
        $scope.changeItem=function (o) {
           console.log(o);
            var value = ($scope.formInfo.name);
            $scope.formInfo.positionId=value;
       }
```

I want use it in ng-change directive like this

```
  <select  ng-options="position.name for position in positionlist" id="inputPosition"  ng-model="formInfo.positionId"  ng-change="changeItem(position)">
```

but my script is printing undefined value on console.

Comment: Calm down, you're messing up a bit. You already have the `ngModel`, so for what you need to pass as *parameter* again? Also your function makes no sense.. please, provide more info about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also you cant try ng-change="changeItem(formInfo.positionId)", but I agree to @developer033 that your code looks weird. $scope.formInfo.positionId is already contains selected item, so no need to use ngChange - item name is in $scope.formInfo.positionId.name. Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmj0px6e/)

Comment: I want to parse it without quotes. I can't delete it by substring method so I thought that this will be a good way

Comment: Do you want to parse what? Edit your question providing your `array` structure (`positionlist`) and we can help.